# MS SQL : Full Text Search Results are not relevant

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am trying MS SQL Full Text Query on single column.

For this I am using "FREETEXTABLE" function.

When I query "Horse ride" the result set contains videos where title contain the word "ride".

No wonder that when using FREE or "FREETEXTTABLE" the process is to break query string
 into words, create inflectional words and that is how the result set get generated.

So my question is if this is the process, why the result set have no video where the "horse" word is
 present (I have videos in DB where videos title contains the "horse" word).

Is it because the word breaker gives preference to "verbs" ?

Please comment on how "word breaker" and "stemmer" works for English language.

Links where I could find grate details about "word breaker" and "stemmer" will also be 
 help full.

This is very important for me to get relevant results every time.

Thank you.

Comment: You should provide more info on your table/query/indexes
I tend to split the search string and use `formsof(inflectional,...` on each part (combined with a `OR`). see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4727055/1236044
I also use `containstable(` to be able to order the results by Ranking  desc

Comment: Bellow is my FTS query

CREATE PROC [dbo].[USP_Videos_SearchVideos]
 @searcher varchar(2000)
AS

SELECT Ranker.RANK, v.ViewCount, v.ID, v.TitleText, v.CategoryId,  c.Term,  
FROM mst_Videos AS v INNER JOIN
     FREETEXTTABLE(mst_Videos, TitleText, @searcher) AS Ranker
     ON v.ID = Ranker.[KEY]
     INNER JOIN mst_Categories AS c
     ON v.CategoryId = c.ID

WHERE RANKER.RANK >= 100      
ORDER BY Ranker.RANK DESC, v.ViewCount DESC

Can you suggest any modifications to above query to make it a better so to get more and more relevant results.

Comment: Or if possible, please provide me links where I could find more details about word breaker and stemmer 

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Full text search filters the noise words and punctuations and you have the flexibility of adding more noise words to the default list of noise words. But to manipulate verbs, inflectional or synonyms we can make use of different functions in where clause. 
In your case if you are looking for fields where the word "Horse" AND "ride" exists you can simply make use of Contains function, something like this....

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName
WHERE Contains(ColumnName, '"horse" AND "ride"')
```

If you are looking for values where there is word "Horse" and any inflectional form of "ride" say like ride, riding. You can use something like this ....

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM TableName
WHERE Contains(ColumnName, '"horse"') AND CONTAINS(ColumnName, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, ride)')
```

Comment: If we use Contains it will give all videos where it finds the query words, that way results won't be relevant, because when one searches for "horse ride" the result should conatins videos thoes are about horse riding, if such videos are not present in DB, it may show videos for "horse" and "ride" word when using "FreetextTabel".
But here it is not showing videos which are horse related though it shows videos which are ride related. So my question is same that How does steemer works in FTS ?